# Checkboxes based on user id it save's only one id from all the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form with 10 checkboxes based on user id, but when i check a box in my database i see that only user id 1 checkbox is saving.. please see my code below, any help appreciated!

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="prezente" uid="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">

     <input type="checkbox" name="day1" id="day1" value="1" class="form-check-input">

     <input type="checkbox" name="day2" id="day2" value="1" class="form-check-input">

     <input type="checkbox" name="day3" id="day3" value="1" class="form-check-input">

And so on until day10 ..
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#day1,#day2,#day3').click(function(){

   var id = $('#prezente').attr('uid');
   var day1 = $('input[name=day1]:checked').val();
   var day2 = $('input[name=day2]:checked').val();
   var day3 = $('input[name=day3]:checked').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'sql/add-days.php?uid='+id,
                type: 'post',
                data: { day1: day1,day2: day2,day3: day3 },
                success:function(data){
                  alert("success");
                }
            });
        });
});
```

add-days.php file:

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "stelelea_anapp", "fidodido", "stelelea_anadanceapp");

$day1 = $_POST['day1'];
$day2 = $_POST['day2'];
$day3 = $_POST['day3'];

$uid = $_GET['uid'];

 $query = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `inscrieri` SET day1='$day1',day2='$day2',day3='$day3' WHERE id = $uid");
```

Here is how my checkboxses look like, one cercle represents a day:

[image]

Comment: So you're saying if the first checkbox you click is #4, it doesn't update any of them?

Comment: yes , exactly..

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that should cause that to happen.  Is this exactly the code that you have in the js and php?

Comment: Though one question.  `uid="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">` makes it seem like you may have multiple of these forms on the page?

Comment: yes this is the code, if i check the user id 2 checkbox it says that user has id 1 and so on .. on all users it grabs only id 1

Comment: yes @Taplar , multiple forms with checkboxes for all the users

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you are repeating ids.  Ids are expected to be unique per page.  You need to change this logic to use classes instead, which will allow you to do the logic you are trying to do

Comment: I have tried that and nothing.. i'm not so good with coding but i see that it saves in database only checkboxes of user id #1 even if i click on checkboxes of user id 2,3,and so on.. it says that all of them has id 1

Comment: Take a look at my answer.  I've converted it to use classes and find the related fields with contextual lookups.

Comment: Also modified it to default to 0 if a checkbox is not checked so the backend isn't trying to insert 'undefined' @Fido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the html and javascript to use classes, with contextual lookups.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //bind on the shared class so you don't have to look for multiple ids or classes
  $('.day').click(function() {
    //get the form that is the parent of the day clicked
    var $form = $(this).closest('.prezente');
    //get the id of the form
    var id = $form.attr('uid');
    //get the days that belong to the form
    //if the field is not checked, it would not be found and would return
    //  undefined for the val(), in which case we can default to 0
    var day1 = $form.find('.day1:checked').val() || 0;
    var day2 = $form.find('.day2:checked').val() || 0;
    var day3 = $form.find('.day3:checked').val() || 0;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'sql/add-days.php?uid=' + id,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        day1: day1,
        day2: day2,
        day3: day3
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" class="prezente" uid="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="day1" value="1" class="day day1 form-check-input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="day2" value="1" class="day day2 form-check-input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="day3" value="1" class="day day3 form-check-input">
</form>
```